# Are there any reasons you wouldn't want to use the Static Analyzer every time you build your iOS app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I'm diving into iOS development and I just found out about the Static Analyzer and it's been pointing out all sorts of mistakes I was making in the code.  The Static Analyzer doesn't really seem to eat up any extra time when building and so I'm wondering why it isn't enabled by default.

Are there any reasons you wouldn't want to use the Static Analyzer every time you build your iOS app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly because it does eat up extra time when you build your app. Your app is probably pretty small or you'd notice the difference. When your app takes 10-20 minutes just to compile, you're more likely to just run static analysis "from time to time." Before you commit is a good time to do it.

Comment: I would second this, but would argue that unless your build time is less than 30 seconds, cutting down build time is a very important goal.  There's been all kinds of studies regarding knowledge work (like software development), and how concentration is key.  When a build interrupts your work flow for even a few seconds, people's attention tends to wander, producing more mental context switching, and actually significantly reducing productivity.  I think commit time is the perfect time to run these kinds of checks ... coupled with the suggestion that committing often is usually good.

Answer (score 8):

No, I use it all the time. One cannot have enough help tracking down all the bugs :-)

Comment: thanks, anders.  while we're on the topic, are there any other goodies that aren't turned on by default that you recommend I start using?

Comment: For debug builds switch to the CLANG/LLVM 1.5 compiler, which will give you even more warnings...

Comment: @BeachRunnerJoe: "Treat Warnings as Errors." That should definitely have been turned on by default.